# Convert jpeg image into byte array using python in raspberry pi

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, numpy, raspberry-pi

I want to convert jpeg image into byte array using python in raspberry pi 3.The image will be available in port:8081 which is host on http ip address(eg:http:192.12.12.12:8081) of raspberry pi using motion Library.so i want to convert the http ip which has the image into byte array.

Comment: What should be the mime type of the resource application/octet-stream?The url will be http://{host}:8081/ ?

Comment: It will be like http://<IP>:8081/ and its format is .jpeg  
IP address mention above is the IP of raspberry pi

Comment: did you get any solution for this?